# What is the best way to create a UI for an existing Google-Apps-Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script using "Google-Apps-Script" that checks if an email has a specific label and a star, and then it takes the email attachment and sends it to another email address.

The script is working fine, but now I want to create a UI where the user can look at the attachment, fill out some text fields and this would result in the file being renamed.

I would then have a button to send that renamed attachment to another email address.

What would be the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have listed, I would go this route to create a GUI for that purpose.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#create_html_files
You can use an HTML page as the GUI while the script handles everything on the back end.